# What do the short parallel lines mean in a symmetrical value?

Tags: technical-drawing, drawings

[image]

I was wondering if the short parallel lines at the ends mean anything?

Comment: It represents perpendicular and vertical alignment to Cartesian planes

Comment: @Rhodie  Cartesian planes ? seriously ? And how does it help us  why we need ?  Do you have any reference ? I have never encountered cartesian planes or any other coordinates systems getting involve in technical drawing.

Comment: When drawing in model space there are 3 axes: x, y & z. Those are the Cartesian planes. The parallel lines indicate that they continue infinitely onwards beyond the drawing space.

Answer (score 1):

Those short parallel lines have absolutely no meaning in terms of information relating to the part, but we put them on the drawing to identify the line of symmetry. They are always at the right angles to the symmetry line.

There are also another parallel lines that you may encounter later, to know more about technical drawing symbols, it's good to look at GD&T tables, symbols and definitions.